# Can't connect to remote oracle db with ruby-oci8, ORA-06401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, oci8

I'm trying to use a remote db in my rails app. To accomplish this I'm using ruby-oci8 following this instructions: http://www.pixellatedvisions.com/2009/03/26/rails-on-oracle-part-2-setting-up-rails-to-connect-to-an-oracle-database

I have no problems with part 1, connecting to the remote db via sqlplus, but when I try to use oci8:

```
ruby -r oci8 -e "OCI8.new('user', 'pass', 'host_ip:port/sid').exec('SELECT * FROM table') {|r| puts ' | ' r.join}"
```

I get:

```
oci8.c:267:in oci8lib_191.so: ORA-06401: NETCMN: invalid driver designator (OCIError)
        from -e:1:in `new'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Googling this error I read this http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_06401_netcmn_invalid_driver_designator.htm wich gives no help at all to my case.
I also read that I should have a TNSNAMES.ORA file, wich I don't... so I created one without any luck.

BTW i'm using ruby-oci8-2.0.6-x86-mingw32.gem (cause I'm in windows), ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.3

Any clue?

**EDIT**

Googled a little more and found:

- Problem Description: Cannot run Health Check on some of her databases. Getting error "ORA-06401: NETCMN: invalid driver designator" and Health Check then displays a note of "Connection Failure (1)". There is no problems connection to this database directly from Toad's connection window.
- Cause:Issue specific to using a direct connection on a 9i client and selecting a direct connect database in Health Check.
- Resolution:
  RESOLUTION 1:Connect using a different method, choose to connect as TNS instead of Direct. In this case you can use your 9i client.
  RESOLUTION 2:Connect using a different client, upgrade to either 10g or 11g client if you need to use direct connect.

Comment: post your tnsnames.ora file?  did you set your TNS_ADMIN env to point to your tnsnames.ora file location?  if you are using the tnsname, then you can change your connection in ruby to "OCI8.new('user', 'pass', 'tnsalias')..."  If you don't want to use the tnsalias, then check to see what service the listener on the database is using (lsnrctl status listener) its the service name you want to use like this "OCI8.new('user', 'pass', 'host_ip:port/service_name')..."

Comment: If I connect via sqlplus using: `sqlplus user/pass@//host_ip
:port/sid` shouldn't I be able to just use "OCI8.new('user', 'pass', 'host_ip:port/service_name')..." ?? Sorry....I've never used oracle db before

Comment: Is the tsnames.ora file always required?

Comment: tnsnames isn't always needed but it simplifies some things.  For ruby, the connection is looking for a service_name instead of a sid.  So check your listener for the service name that its listening on for your database.  Then in ruby the //host_ip:port/service_name connection should work.

Comment: Wont do.... the client oracle version need to be the same as the server?

Comment: are you running the sqlplus test and the test with ruby with the same os user? what oracle versions are using for the two different databases?

Comment: no the client doesn't need to be the same version as the server.  the client can be a few version behind the server and vice versa.  If the client/server version are close enough it should work.  Can you post your listener status so i can see what service name its listening on.  you can X-out the ips for security.

Comment: Yep, it's the same os user and the server uses Oracle 9i, client has Instant Client 10. And I don't know how to run lsnrctl since I only have the client in my computer and don't have access to the server :S

Comment: that client should work with oracle 9 fine.  have you tried puting the sqlplus syntax into ruby "oci8.new('user/pass@//host_ip:port/sid')"  if that doesn't work then ask the dba what the service name database is.

Comment: what's the difference between that and `sqlplus user/pass@//host_ip :port/sid` if I can do it via mysql, then the sid is correct and I should be able to do it via oci8.new... am I wrong?